# Creating grid layer of 2 km sq. and deciding X and Y parameters?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

How to create a Vector Gird polygon layer and what should put in the X and Y parameters when I would like to create a 2 km sq grid polygon

Comment: Which software are you using? Pls check the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question...

Answer (score 3):

If the projection that you are using has meter unit such as UTM, then you can just write 2000 in cell width OR cell height mutiply by 1000 for Cell width or height, depending the shape that you want, if you are using [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) tool in ArcGIS. In QGIS you can go to `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid`, and enter 2000 for x OR y multiply by 1000 for x OR y to specify the with and height of cells. You can select polygon grid or polyline grid, and this also applies to ArcGIS. If you need higher resolution you can specify 4000 x 500 OR 400 x 5000 depending on the shape.

Comment: It is not working when I put 2000 for both X and Y, need more help on it

Comment: What projection are you using?

Comment: I am using UTM (WGS 84, 46N)

Comment: By default value in QGIS for X and Y is 0.0001000000, Could you please tell me what does it mean?

Comment: 2km x 2 km = 4 sq.km -1 btw

Comment: @FelixIP Sorry I read the question in different way. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't get FelixIP, Only my question is the X and Y cell value, and  could you please  let me know the unit used for defaulter in QGIS

Comment: Check the lower right corner of QGIS there is EPSG that shows the current projection used in your project. If it is WGS84, then you are using the wrong projection. If you UTM (WGS 84, 46N), then you need to specify the suggested values, since the projection is already in meter.

Comment: @ ahmadhanb, it is EPSG 4326

Comment: This means the default EPSG is WGS84.

Comment: If you are referencing a layer that is in UTM (WGS 84, 46N) then load that data in a new QGIS project file, then follow the instruction of the answer. The default EPSG should be chaged to UTM (WGS 84, 46N).

Comment: okay @ahmadhanb, but my concern is the X or Y value, what should be correct figure for 2 km sq grid cell?

Comment: X and Y are distances. As I explained in my answer if you want 2 sq.km, it means 2 km multiply 1 km OR 1 km multiply 2 km, which means 2000 m multiply 1000 m or vise versa. You have to specify the values in meter.

Comment: For square cell, it is approx. 1.4142 km. 1 km= 1000 m